# What is an idiom for a person who likes himself too much?

Tags: idioms

I want to ask you about an idiom in Arabic, especially used in Iraq. It is about the groundnut plant which has a different colors before it blooms; however, we use this idiom for a person who likes himself too much, so is there an equivalent in English?

Comment: We can't read your mind—you're going to have to give us at least a rough translation of the idiom into English.

Comment: Also, we're going to need *how* and why you use the idiom "for a person who likes himself too much". I can't see how that is connected to a plant being of different colours.

Comment: You’ll also have to tell us _what the idiom is_. What you’ve told us is that you have an idiom that’s related somehow to the groundnut plant and is used for people who like themselves too much. That says virtually nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a **narcissist**:

> an extremely self-centered person who has an exaggerated sense of self-importance

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narcissist)

Interestingly, this also has a plant connection. The word comes from a character in Greek mythology:

> a beautiful youth in Greek mythology who pines away for love of his own reflection and is then turned into the narcissus flower

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narcissus)